# Custom designing of inbuilt Scroll bar or Scroll Viewer of Datagrid in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

can any one please suggest me how to change style of inbuilt scroll viewer of `DataGrid` in Silverlight.

Right now my `DataGrid` is taking the default style of scroll viewer which is used in the project so I want to change that is it possible if yes then please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Expression Blend, in design mode you can right-click the datagrid > Edit Template >    Edit a Copy.

In the window "Objects and TimeLine" will appear the inbuilt components, including the Horizontal and Vertical ScrollBars:

[image]

After that, in the "Objects and TimeLine" window, you right-click the ScrollBars > Edit Template > Edit Current. The XAML Window will show the ScrollBar Style:

[image]

I recommend you mannually duplicate the entire Style and make changes in the copy.